# If $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx <C \|g\|_1$ then there exists $M>0$ s.t. $f(x)<M$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a function on the interval $[0,1]$. If $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx <C \|g\|_1$ for all nonnegative function $g\in L^1[0,1]$ then show that there is a constant $M>0$ such that $f(x)<M$ almost everywhere in $[0,1]$.

**Attempt.** Suppose not. Then there is a subset $A\subseteq [0,1]$ with $m(A)>0$ such that $f(x)=\infty$ for all $x\in A$. So, $\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx\geq\int_Af(x)g(x)\,dx=m(A)\cdot\infty=\infty$, contradiction.

I would be glad if someone could check my attempt or give a hint. Thanks!

Comment: Your negation of "there exists $M>0$ such that $f(x) < M$ almost everywhere" is incorrect. It should "for any $M > 0$, we have $m(\{x : f(x) > M\}) > 0$." The intersection $\bigcap_{M > 0} \{x : f(x) > M\}$ is $\{x : f(x) = \infty\}$ but this may have measure zero. Concrete counterexample: $f(x) = 1/x$ is not bounded almost surely, but $\{x : f(x) = \infty\}$ has measure zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose not. Then for all $M>0$, we have $m\bigl(\{x\in[0,1] : f(x)>M\} \bigr) > 0$.

Now fix any $M>0$, and let $A_M := \{x \in [0,1] : f(x)>M\}$. Since $A_M$ is a measurable set, we know that $\mathbf{1}_{A_M} \in L^1[0,1]$, where $\mathbf{1}_{A_M}$ is the characteristic function of $A_M$. We can calculate
$$
\int_0^1 f \mathbf{1}_{A_M} \,\mathrm{d}m = \int_{A_M} f \,\mathrm{d}m > \int_{A_M} M \,\mathrm{d}m = M \int \mathbf{1}_{A_M} \,\mathrm{d}m = M \|\mathbf{1}_{A_M}\|_1.
$$
However, by hypothesis, we have that $\int_0^1 f\mathbf{1}_{A_M} \,\mathrm{d}m < C\|\mathbf{1}_{A_M}\|_1$. Hence
$$
M \|\mathbf{1}_{A_M}\|_1 < \int_0^1 f\mathbf{1}_{A_M} \,\mathrm{d}m < C \|\mathbf{1}_{A_M}\|_1.
$$
Since $m(A_M) > 0$, then $\|\mathbf{1}_{A_M}\|_1 > 0$, so we can divide by $\|\mathbf{1}_{A_M}\|_1$ to conclude that $M < C$.

So for all $M>0$, we can conclude that $C>M$, which contradicts $C \in \mathbb{R}$.